# Set some background color only for login page

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to give my login page some background color(only for my login page)
For that, I have built a directive in my shared folder

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  Renderer2,
  Input,
  AfterViewInit
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appBackground]"
})
export class BackgroundDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}
  @Input() backgroundColor: string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(
      this.el.nativeElement,
      "background-color",
      this.backgroundColor
    );
  }
}
```

and then in my login component, I am doing this

```
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  color: string;
  emailFormControl = new FormControl("", [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(EMAIL_REGEX)
  ]);
  passwordFormControl = new FormControl("", [Validators.required]);
  constructor(private dir: BackgroundDirective) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.dir);
    this.dir.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  }
}
```

and then in login.component.html

```
<div BackgroundDirective>
// my login page content
</div>
```

But I see no change in my login page background color, what I am missing?
[image]

Comment: `document.querySelector('body').style['background-color'] = 'red'`

Comment: I am using renderer

Comment: you don't need the directive and renderer. you can use the `router` inside the component and check for the `url` and set the color as this way. and remove the same in `ngOnDestroy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your example. [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enuqxq) is a stackblitz implementing your code

1/ Directive are meant to be used in an HTML declarative way. You don't have to inject it in your constructor (for simple cases)

2/ your selector is [appBackground] so you have to use your directive this way. You have to use the chosen selector, not the directive ClassName

```
<div appBackground>...</div>
```

3/ your added an Input on your directive (@Input() backgroundColor: string;)

so if you want to set the color you can use it this way

```
<div appBackground backgroundColor="red"></div>
```

4/ don't forget to add your directive in the declarations parts of your module.

Comment: I have this directive in my shared folder and CLI has already added this directive at declaration part of sharedModule. and I am importing sharedmodule in my auth module(where my login component reside). still I need to declare this directive in declaration part of auth module to make it work?

Comment: no, my bad, i misread the sharedModule part of your description. If it is declared ( and exported ! ) in the sharedModule, and the sharedModule is imported in LoginModule you are good to go